# Select a row from secondary dataframe to place adjacent to primary dataframe fulfilling a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have two dataframes which are ranked in the order of priority (i.e higher priority at the top and lower priority at bottom) and they need to be appended (meaning combine all the columns to build a new table) with row 1 of dataframe 1 placed adjacent of row 1 of dataframe 2 but it should skip to the next available row if current row of second dataframe does not fullfill the condition described below.

The first dataframe (check) has an ID column ('rmkt_account_managers_id') which needs to be assigned a merchant from second dataframe (df) with a condition that the 'assigned_from' which is another column in second dataframe (df) does not match with the representative ID(('rmkt_account_managers_id') to which the merchant will be assigned.

Here is what I did but it doesn't work:

```py
import random
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Downloads\LRPool_Leads_1st_April_19.xlsx')
df['merchant_id'] = pd.to_numeric(df['merchant_id'])
df['assigned_from'] = pd.to_numeric(df['assigned_from'])
df['assignment_done']=0

df1=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Downloads\assignments_to_be_done.xlsx')

check=df1.reindex(df1.index.repeat(df1.Assignments))
check['C'] = check.groupby('rmkt_account_managers_id')['rmkt_account_managers_id'].cumcount()
check.sort_values(by=['C', 'rmkt_account_managers_id'], inplace=True)

check['action']="ADD"
check['Remarketing_Account_Type']="ACCOUNT"
check['merchant_id']=""
check['rmkt_account_managers_id'] = pd.to_numeric(check['rmkt_account_managers_id'])

for i, row in check.iterrows(): 
    for j, row2 in df.iterrows(): 
        if ((row['rmkt_account_managers_id'] != row2['assigned_from']) & (row2['assignment_done'] !=1) & (row['merchant_id'] !=0)): 
            row.loc['merchant_id'] = row2.loc['merchant_id'] 
            row2.loc['assignment_done'] = 1 
        else:
            row2.loc['assignment_done'] = 0
        
check.to_excel(r'C:\Downloads\result.xlsx', sheet_name='assignments', index = False)
```

Assignment Done is column I wanted to use as helper

Example:
df name: `check`

```
{'rmkt_account_managers_id': [792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980, 6364038, 6389945, 6421707, 792, 649741, 1506572, 2159133, 2435783, 2710213, 3469133, 4085263, 5048463, 5112823, 5279163, 6192544, 6204534, 6235820, 6255350, 6272151, 6272180, 6286834, 6305702, 6329553, 6341883, 6341890, 6341910, 6341913, 6342486, 6342635, 6351103, 6360980], 'action': ['ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD', 'ADD'], 'Remarketing_Account_Type': ['ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT', 'ACCOUNT']}
```

Expected Output:

```
'rmkt_account_managers_id' 'action' 'Remarketing_Account_Type' 'Merchant ID'
```

Comment: Please add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question

Comment: Hi @Rabinzel, I added MRE

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what you want to do here. Why the `Representative_ID` repeats in df1? Shouldn't it be unique? You iterate from top to bottom in df1[`Representative_ID`] and assign a `Merchant_ID` from df2 to it (also picked from top to bottom) and only when in column `old representative ID` is the same as the current `representative_ID` then skip to the next `Merchant_ID` ?

Comment: ->Shouldn't it be unique? 
Not it is not unique as each representative Id will get more than 1 merchant so they are repeated in Df1.

->You iterate from top to bottom in df1[Representative_ID] and assign a Merchant_ID from df2 to it (also picked from top to bottom) and only when in column old representative ID is the same as the current representative_ID then skip to the next Merchant_ID ? 
Yes, exactly

Comment: @Rabinzel Did I answer your questions?
Let me know if I can provide more information on this.
Thanks a lot

Comment: You are sure you run that code like this? If I run your code with your provided data, I get error because there is no `assignment_done` column in df. So far so good,I just add it, then I run into the next problem: `row['merchant_id']` does also not exist (row refers to `check` where no such column is.)

Comment: I added the full code now. I had to delete one Df as I don't have that many characters to add both in the question.

Comment: you're lucky I already copied that :D

Comment: It is a little frustrating with you to be honest. I don't know how many times I asked to tell me the exact structure of your dataframes ( doesn't matter if 100000 rows or 10, but all the columns and the names). `Check` clearly has a column named `C`..... df has this `assignment_done` column. These differences have impact on the answer I provide. Here is what I do now. I try (can't really tell) to take your code here and apply it to my answer to make it work for you ok?

Comment: I updated my answer, please exactly copy paste it like that and see if it works

Comment: Also important: When I create the variable `pairs` I rely on the fact that in `df` the 1st column is `merchant_id` and the 2nd column is `assigned_from`. The order is important here

Comment: Can you also guide me through it a bit

Comment: have you already read my explanation in my answer? I tried to explain how it works. If you still have questions, tell me and I will add more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of any good way to solve this in pandas itself with sorting/grouping or anything else.
Since you always want to fill the rows from top to bottom and always want to find the first `merchand_id` which can be assigned to a `rmkt_account_managers_id` I think [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is useful here.

Basically we create a `deque` of the data of DataFrame `df`, where each element is a tuple like `(39191, 6342486.0)` in the order like the rows appear in `df`.
`deque's` are preferred over lists where you have to use append and pop operations from both the ends of your data/stack.
We loop through each row of DataFrame `check`, pop the first element of the deque (`take_first`) and while equal to the `assigned_from` we continue popping the first element till we find one that fits the condition. After that we use `appendleft` to add the non-used tuples back to the `deque`.
At the end we have a list called `result` which we assign to a new column.

I deleted both old answers, it just makes things confusing.
I can't follow the logic of your attempt, too many things that are not understandable for me what you actually want to achieve.
I used exactly the naming you provided with the exact same data in your question and this is my code that is working properly on it.

Try to copy paste just this code and see if it works:

```
import random
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Downloads\LRPool_Leads_1st_April_19.xlsx')
df['merchant_id'] = pd.to_numeric(df['merchant_id'])
df['assigned_from'] = pd.to_numeric(df['assigned_from'])


df1=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Downloads\assignments_to_be_done.xlsx')
check=df1.reindex(df1.index.repeat(df1.Assignments))
check['C'] = check.groupby('rmkt_account_managers_id')['rmkt_account_managers_id'].cumcount()
check['rmkt_account_managers_id'] = pd.to_numeric(check['rmkt_account_managers_id'])
check.sort_values(by=['C', 'rmkt_account_managers_id'], inplace=True)

check['action']="ADD"
check['Remarketing_Account_Type']="ACCOUNT"

pairs = deque(df.itertuples(name=None, index=None)) 

result = [] 
for row in check['rmkt_account_managers_id']: 
    if pairs: 
        take_first = pairs.popleft() 
        tmp=[] 
        while take_first[1] == row:
            tmp.append(take_first) 
            take_first = pairs.popleft() 
        if tmp: 
            pairs.extendleft(tmp[::-1])
        result.append(take_first[0]) 
check.loc[:,'new_Merchant_ID'] = result
print(check.head(10))
        
check.to_excel(r'C:\Downloads\result.xlsx', sheet_name='assignments', index = False)
```

Output:

```
   rmkt_account_managers_id action Remarketing_Account_Type  new_Merchant_ID
0                       792    ADD                  ACCOUNT            39191
1                    649741    ADD                  ACCOUNT            84173
2                   1506572    ADD                  ACCOUNT          6235186
3                   2159133    ADD                  ACCOUNT           353171
4                   2435783    ADD                  ACCOUNT           282081
5                   2710213    ADD                  ACCOUNT          6233030
6                   3469133    ADD                  ACCOUNT           911811
7                   4085263    ADD                  ACCOUNT             1186
8                   5048463    ADD                  ACCOUNT            24945
9                   5112823    ADD                  ACCOUNT            15156
```

Comment: The result is not exactly what I expected, I get following output:


| representative_ID| new_Merchant_ID |
| -------------------|---------------------|
| Am1                    |    M1                      |
| Am1                    |    M1                      |
| Am1                    |    M1                      |
| Am1                    |    M1                      |
| Am1                    |    M1                      |
| Am1                    |    M1                      |
| Am1                    |    M1                      |

Comment: Yes, I changed accordingly.

check_temp=check[['rmkt_account_managers_id']]
df_temp=df[['merchant_id','assigned_from']]

pairs = deque(df_temp.itertuples(name=None, index=None))
print(pairs)

result = []
for row in check_temp['rmkt_account_managers_id']:
    if pairs:
        take_first = pairs.popleft()
        tmp=[]
        while take_first[1] == row:
            tmp.append(take_first)
            take_first = pairs.popleft()
        if tmp:
            pairs.extendleft(tmp[::-1])
        result.append(take_first[0])

check_temp['new_Merchant_ID'] = pd.Series(result)

Comment: So what it did is, it assigned that same one merchant to the each repeated value of representative id in final result.

print(df.to_dict('list')) has following columns:
merchant_id, company, no_of_evaluations, number_bids, merchant_score, assigned_from

Here column merchant_id is unique. (assigned_from is old representative ID)

print(check.to_dict('list')) has following columns:

rmkt_account_managers_id, Account_Type,action    

Here rmkt_account_managers_id is repeated N times for each ID. N depends on the number of merchants to be assigned to the account_manager.

Comment: I just added it in the question.

Comment: Hi Rabinzel,
I still get the same result (repeated merchant Ids for each accoynt manager). I pasted the result in my question.

Comment: I made a subset dataframe of the main dataframe to provide in the result of print(check.to_dict('list')) and print(df.to_dict('list')). But yes, I used those subset of dataframe in the code you shared me to use.

Comment: It does not seem to work. I have tried everything. I reworked on the code I initially wrote:

for i, row in check.iterrows():
    for j, row2 in df.iterrows():
        if ((row['rmkt_account_managers_id'] != row2['assigned_from']) & (row2['assignment_done'] !=1) & (row['merchant_id'] !=0)):
            
            row.loc['merchant_id'] = row2.loc['merchant_id']
            row2.loc['assignment_done'] = 1
        
        else: row2.loc['assignment_done'] = 0

(I have added the code in the question, but the code does not provide the result as needed now. Do you see errors?)

Comment: Ah, thanks for that!!

Can you share with me the input data you used for your code? I will try to see on my end too, what is not working. 
I am also confused why it happens like this.

Comment: Hi Rabinzel.

Sure, I edited the whole question with exact data frames I have as input with all the columns named as in my datframe.

Thanks for quick replies.

Comment: Also, to add I get following warning on running the code:
C:\Users\nitish.dwivedi\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17340\2340993931.py:45: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  check_print['new_Merchant_ID'] = pd.Series(result)

Comment: Also, if you want I can write the complete code I am using in the question.

Comment: You propably get this warning because you created `check_print` from your full check dataframe with a slice. Then later, when you try to add the new column to that sliced dataframe, you get a warning. If you just run that code on your full dataframe instead of making it smaller as example, then you won't get this warning.